# סדורה breaks in the Torah

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, sefer-torah, safrus

The [Tur Yoreh Deah 275](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Yoreh_Deah.275.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) describes three kinds of breaks in the Sefer Torah. The first two types are פתוחה and סתומה, the standard "open" and "closed" breaks. He and the Beis Yosef there bring various opinions on how to do them.
The Tur then describes a third type, the סדורה, where a line ends somewhere in the middle, and the next line begins in the same place but one line lower:

> ועוד יש בתיקון סופרים פרשה   סדורה והוא שכתב שיטה עד חצייה או עד
> שלישיתה ומתחיל בשיטה תחתיה כנגד הנחת העליונה ונראה שאם שינה בזה לא פסל
> כיון שאינו מפורש בגמרא

Attempted drawing:

```
                                     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The Beis Yosef and later poskim discusses whether this is a variety of סתומה or a third type, and what happens if you switch it with the other type or leave it out.
My question is, What happened to these? As the Aruch Hashulchan [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.275.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), we just don't have any of them in our sifrei Torah. Do we know where they used to be, and do we have old sifrei Torah that contain סדורות? (The Rambam does not mention these at all.)

Comment: If we hold they are just another regular stumah then there's no special reason to include them, especially if the rosh and rambam would disagree what they mean.

Comment: A note: some very old texts use the term "parsha sdura" differently to mean there is no gap (even if you might think there'd have been one there; like saying it's a "run-on parsha"). You have to be careful to pay attention to what your text intends.

Comment: @DoubleAA For example, I was trying to find one in the Leningrad Codex, not much luck. Do you know of texts that do show them?

Comment: Less than a minute flipping through Leningrad yields this at the beginning of lech lcha https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d4/Leningrad-codex-01-genesis.pdf/page11-1275px-Leningrad-codex-01-genesis.pdf.jpg Is that what you sought? Leningrad is from an area where this form would just be considered a regular closed portion so it will show up randomly at closed breaks.

Comment: @DoubleAA I saw several like this that resembed a sedurah (I assume you're referring to the last one on the page). But as far as I got, all stumos were either the standard in the middle of the line (ובנות... וארפכשד) or if there wasn't room, always the exactly same indentation at the beginning of the line, like all the others on this page, starting w ויחי עבר. I had trouble finding one that was indented far enough that I was sure it didn't just work out that way from the previous line. Like if ויחי תרח had started two-thirds in, past ובנות.

Comment: That last one is a drop further over than ויחי רעו, but I wanted more.